# Powershell email output not formatting correctly

Tags: email, powershell

I have spent the last few hours trying various ways to solve my problem below, adding parts from other working scripts that I have and researching on here, yet have reached the point where I need a fresh set of eyes to point the obvious out to me.

This is my script, which does the following:

- Lists all folders in a certain location, puts the folder paths in a text file
- In a loop, uses the text file to check the most recent file in each folder, then output the most recent 10 timestamps (denoted by '[')
- Emails the results

All of the above works, I have the email with the correct information. The problem is that the email arrives all on the same line with no formatting.

I've taken my style tags from a previous working script that I had, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Any ideas?

```
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding:     5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"
$subject = "Processing Log Check at " + (Get-Date -Format g)
$logpaths = Get-Content -Path C:\Powershell\xxxx\scenariologlocation.txt 
$output = foreach ($logpath in $logpaths)
{
Write-Output $logpath
Get-ChildItem -path $logpath | sort LastWriteTime | select -ExpandProperty FullName -last 1 | Out-File C:\Powershell\path.txt
$path = Get-Content -Path C:\Powershell\path.txt
Get-Content -Path $path | Select-String -SimpleMatch "[" | select Line -last 10 | format-table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
}
$body = (ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -body $output | Out-String)
Send-MailMessage -From "xxxxxx" -To "xxxxxx" -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer "xxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't pass a string to `$output` and then pass it to `Convertto-Html -body`

In my eyes the last part of the script should look like

```
$output = foreach ($logpath in $logpaths)
{
Write-Output $logpath
Get-ChildItem -path $logpath | sort LastWriteTime | select -ExpandProperty FullName -last 1 | Out-File C:\Powershell\path.txt
$path = Get-Content -Path C:\Powershell\path.txt
Get-Content -Path $path | Select-String -SimpleMatch "[" | select Line -last 10
}
$body = ($output | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style) | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -From "xxxxxx" -To "xxxxxx" -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer "xxxxxxx"
```

So that `Convertto-Html` could build the table over all objects in `$output`. I don't really know if it is necessary to pipe the HTML to `Out-String`. Have no Powershell here. But I think this should help.

Comment: Thanks, this gives progress, it produces a formatted email, however the content produced is now incorrect. I will tinker a bit and see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling and fanoodling, I ended up re-writing the lot and got what I needed into an email another way.

I'm not 100% convinced what I needed could be achieved from my original code (without resorting to the re-write).